# Is there any difference except of the prepositions?

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs, superlatifs

In the below examples:

> Sophie est moins sérieuse **que** les autres.
>
> Sophie est la plus grande **de** la classe.

- Why is the former *comparative* and the latter *superlative*? Is is
  related to the preposition "de" and "que"?
- As far as I know, in superlative form there should not be a
  reference, am I right? If yes, why the latter has one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in superlative form, there is no reference. But in your example, *de la classe* isn't a **reference** but a **restriction**. You can also say:

> "Sophie est la plus grande."

It's still in superlative form.

- You can spot a comparative form when the preposition *que* is present and introducing a reference.
- You can spot a superlative form when an article (*le*, *la* or *les*) is present just before the comparison. In your example, it's *la* (***la*** *plus grande*).

The preposition *de* (or others) introducing a restriction is optional and can be present in comparative form too:

> "Sophie est plus grande que les autres dans ce groupe."